# How to test the spacing between electrical contacts

Tags: electrical

https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3350225/The-flexible-sheet-THOUSANDS-times-thinner-paper-Ultralight-material-revolutionise-gadgets-planes.html

What materials besides the above can you think of that is thinner than paper? is a razor blade thinner than paper? I need it to test the spacing between electrical contacts between spring clip of a circuit breaker and bus bar by putting it in between (see pic below). Any that is even dozens of times thinner than paper will be fine as long as I can buy it (I couldn't buy the 1000 times thinner than paper material above).

[image: 2]

Comment: A razor blade is quite a bit thicker than paper. Typical copy paper in the US (what we call "20 lb") is about 1/200 of an inch, or 1/10 millimeter. If the spacing on these bus bars is a lot smaller than that, it is effectively "0". Not quite sure what the goal is here.

Comment: just want test if the electrical contact is only at the bottom... if there is even 1/10 millimeter spacing, there is still no full electrical contact as electricity can't simply cross the 1/10 millimeter gap

Comment: I just don't see why you would need something thinner than a typical piece of paper.

Comment: Now I saw a candy wrapper and used it to insert between the contacts.. it's even wider see pic  https://imageshack.com/a/img921/5026/B06T1m.jpg           meaning only the bottom is in contact.. i'm hoping the other side has larger contact area so need to test with even thinner material

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you're doing this but how about calipers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with home improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Get a [feeler gauge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BYGIR4) like this one 
[image]

[image]

> This OEMTOOLS 26 Blade Master Feeler Gauge is perfect for measuring gap widths and other vital measurements. Each blade has been laser etched with SAE and Metric sizes and constructed by hardened, tempered steel. This OEMTOOLS Feeler Gauge also features a thumb notch for easy blade removal. Sizes range from 0.0015 Inch (0.038 mm) to 0.025 Inch (0.635 mm)